# Android TextView with ellipsize attribute moved from the original position

Tags: android, textview, attr, longtext

I have found a strange behavior with the Android TextView and the ellipsize attribute.
When the text is long and the ellipsize attribute is applied, the original position of the text is lost and the text appears a bit upper.

Yes, I can solve it programatically, but I would like to know if it could be a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

A very simple example to test it. 
Change the text of two textview to see the text ellipsized or not like I'm showing on the last screenshots. If you compare the screenshots you'll see the issue.

I have tested it with 'dp' and 'sp' to see if it could be a different behavior. But it isn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23.3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World! (dp textSize)"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="123.2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World! (sp textSize)"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Short texts under the blocks color perfectly glued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1mpe.png)

[Simply changing the texts with a long string and the texts aren't perfectly glued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03kC3.png)

**SOLUTION:**

The solution is to use the attribute 'singleLine' and then the problem disappear. But AndroidStudio tells me 'singleLine is deprecated'.

Comment: The solution is to use the attribute 'singleLine' and then the problem disappear. But AndroidStudio tells me 'singleLine is deprecated'.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem with font "Courier New" - when 1 line text got ellipsized it moved a few pixels down.
The solution to my problem was to add:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

to wherever i used that font.

Comment: I'll take a look to this option. Thanks!